SQL OpenDataSource read Excel from Network location
I am trying to use OPENDATASOURCE to read an Excel file in Sql Server management Studio.
SELECT top 2 * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source=C:\SSIS\Excel.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO"')...[Sheet1$];

SELECT top 2 * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source=\\app1\App_Files\SSIS\Excel.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO"')...[Sheet1$];

If I run it in SSMS

From my computer
The Excel file is on a network location
Using an Active Directory user (can access the file through explorer, the same user as the SQL Server Service Account)

I get the Error:

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\app1\App_Files\SSIS\Excel.xlsx'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

If I run it with any one (or more) of the following changes it works (see chart below):

From the server instead of my machine
Using an SQL User instead of an Active Directory User
Using a local (to the server) file instead of a network one


Some articles I googled seem to indicate that it might be a Kerberos Double Hop issue. I tried working with the network team and now when I run select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid from my local machine I get



auth_scheme




KERBEROS



but it still doesn't work.
If I run it from the Server (where it does work) I get



auth_scheme




NTLM



It is possible that the network team might not have configured something correctly when trying to setup the fix from the articles about the Kerberos Double Hop issue, but I am not sure how to check for that or even if the issue is with Kerberos at all.

Your user having access is unrelated, it needs to be the SQL Server Service Account that needs access.

@Thom_A I was signed in to SSMS using the same user as the SQL Server Service account

"Ultimately this will be used in SSIS for excel files that do not have consistent column headers or column data types and will need the first row skipped." this makes it sound like an XY Problemn; you are aware that the first row can be skipped when using SSIS too, right?

@ThomA The bigger issue was the inconsistent header names and data types but there are work arounds for those as well. I will remove that bit because this needs to work in other scenarios as well. Thanks

Aside... Microsoft hasn't supported Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 for a while now, as of 2020, might be time to consider upgrading from Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

@AlwaysLearning I also have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 installed. The older one seems to be faster.
